# Which thread does subscriber's onNext() method run on?

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

I have a use case for creating a new Observable:

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
   @Override
   public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
      final RequestFuture<String> futureRequest = RequestFuture.newFuture();
      try{
         //getResult() is a sync time consuming http connection
         String response = getResult();
         subscriber.onNext( response );
         subscriber.onCompleted();
         Log.e("call method","Thread is about to end" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
      }
      catch ( Exception e){
         subscriber.onError( e );
      }

   }
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

So as you can see getResult() method is a http call which is time consuming and im doing it in sync way. And I subscribe it on io thread and observe on Android's main thread.

and when I  retrieve the observable and subscribe to it:

```
subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.e("on completed method", "Thread is ending "+ Thread.currentThread().getId());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Toast.makeText( getContext(), "failed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String s) {
                        Log.e("on Next method", "Thread is about to end" + Thread.currentThread().getId());

                    }
                });
```

the strange thing is i can see the call() method is running on a thread which its id is 372, and the onNext() method from the subscriber is running on thread 1 , i think its the UiThread from android.

so actually how does Rxjava handle this thread change? and it proves that the subscriber in call method is not the one im using in subscribe() method?

Comment: onNext() runs on UiThread I think, where is the implementation of this onNext() method?

Comment: From your implementation `call` is done on one of the `Schedulers.io()` threads, and `onNext` on the main thread. What do you mean by the different subscriber?

Comment: the "subscriber.onNext( response );" in call() and the subscriber from subscribe() method, they are different objects right?

Comment: They are, because the subscriber you pass to `subscribe()` is wrapped in `SafeSubscriber`. If you cast `subscriber` in `call()` to `SafeSubscriber` and call `SafeSubscriber#getActual` on it, you'll get your original object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default subscriber's onNext will run on the same thread you call the `.subscribe`.

In your code however you have two thread changes:

The first is with the `subscribeOn(IO)` which will run the `.create` and the rest of the chain in IO.
After that you have `observeOn(mainThread)` which will change all the following operations to the mainThread, including the final methods in `.subscribe()`.

Hopefully this will give you better understanding of how those two operators work: https://medium.com/@diolor/observe-in-the-correct-thread-1939bb9bb9d2#.t6uagyarn